# Javascript create looping variables

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, loops, variables

[my javascript variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwCUz.png)

```
var select1 = document.getElementById('status-kehadiran1');
select1.onchange = function () {
    select1.classList.remove("hijau");
    select1.classList.remove("merah");
    select1.classList.add(this.options[this.selectedIndex].className);
}
var select2 = document.getElementById('status-kehadiran2');
select2.onchange = function () {
    select2.classList.remove("hijau");
    select2.classList.remove("merah");
    select2.classList.add(this.options[this.selectedIndex].className);
}
var select3 = document.getElementById('status-kehadiran3');
select3.onchange = function () {
    select3.classList.remove("hijau");
    select3.classList.remove("merah");
    select3.classList.add(this.options[this.selectedIndex].className);
}
var select4 = document.getElementById('status-kehadiran4');
select4.onchange = function () {
    select4.classList.remove("hijau");
    select4.classList.remove("merah");
    select4.classList.add(this.options[this.selectedIndex].className);
}
var select5 = document.getElementById('status-kehadiran5');
select5.onchange = function () {
    select5.classList.remove("hijau");
    select5.classList.remove("merah");
    select5.classList.add(this.options[this.selectedIndex].className);
}
var select6 = document.getElementById('status-kehadiran6');
select6.onchange = function () {
    select6.classList.remove("hijau");
    select6.classList.remove("merah");
    select6.classList.add(this.options[this.selectedIndex].className);
}
var select7 = document.getElementById('status-kehadiran7');
select7.onchange = function () {
    select7.classList.remove("hijau");
    select7.classList.remove("merah");
    select7.classList.add(this.options[this.selectedIndex].className);
}
var select8 = document.getElementById('status-kehadiran8');
select8.onchange = function () {
    select8.classList.remove("hijau");
    select8.classList.remove("merah");
    select8.classList.add(this.options[this.selectedIndex].className);
}
var select9 = document.getElementById('status-kehadiran9');
select9.onchange = function () {
    select9.classList.remove("hijau");
    select9.classList.remove("merah");
    select9.classList.add(this.options[this.selectedIndex].className);
}
var select10 = document.getElementById('status-kehadiran10');
select10.onchange = function () {
    select10.classList.remove("hijau");
    select10.classList.remove("merah");
    select10.classList.add(this.options[this.selectedIndex].className);
}
```

is there a way to create a looping for those variable to make it more simple?

[my html select elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6vVs.png)

because i have 10 select element with different id

[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrZ88.png)

the purpose of each variable is to change the text color of each select when there is a change of selected option

i hope you can understand my explanation

Comment: Use [event delegation](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation) instead of assigning multiple events — it’s more maintainable, and applies to dynamically added elements. E.g., use an [event argument](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback)’s [`target`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target). See [the tag info](/tags/event-delegation/info) and [What is DOM Event delegation?](/q/1687296/4642212).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use IDs, use a common selector instead for all of those selects - such as `[name^="pertemuan"]` (name attribute starts with pertemuan):

```
for (const select of document.querySelectorAll('[name^="pertemuan"]')) {
    select.addEventListener('change', () => {
        select.classList.remove("hijau", "merah");
        select.classList.add(select.options[select.selectedIndex].className);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first select all the elements with ids using [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and then loop through them and attach the event (*change*) one by one using [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

You can try the following way:

```
//you can select by exact id
//var sel = document.querySelectorAll('#status-kehadiran1, #status-kehadiran2, #status-kehadiran3, #status-kehadiran4, #status-kehadiran5, #status-kehadiran6, #status-kehadiran7, #status-kehadiran8, #status-kehadiran9, #status-kehadiran10');

//you can select by id startsWith selector by matching the common part of each id 
var sel = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=status-kehadiran]');
sel.forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener('change', function(){
    el.classList.remove("hijau", "merah"); //you can remove multiple class separating them with comma
    el.classList.add(el.options[el.selectedIndex].className);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could drop the ids and move `status-kehadiran` to the selects class list. The you can select all of them with [.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and loop over them with [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
document.querySelectorAll('.status-kehadiran')
  .forEach(function(select) {
    select.addEventListener('change', function() {
      this.classList.remove('hijau', 'merah');
      this.classList.add(this.selectedOptions[0].className);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others you can use query selector with name and ids, but you can also assign them a common class and use -

```
document.getElementsByClassName('.name of class')
.forEach(function(select) {
    select.addEventListener('change', function() {
        this.classList.remove('hijau', 'merah');
        this.classList.add(this.selectedOptions[0].className);
    });
});
```